# C# list or array of class

Tags: c#, class, loops

I would like to create multiple objects/instances in a loop. how to do this?

```
class lh 
    {
        public string name;

        public lh(string name)
        {
            this.name = name; ;
        }

    }

while((line = ps.ReadLine()) !=null)
{
      lh a = new lh(line);
}
```

obviously I can't create a new object using the same name (a) over and over again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<lh> objects = new List<lh>();

while(your_condition)
{
    objects.Add(new lh(line));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about a list or array?

```
List<lh> lines = new List<lh>();

while((line = ps.ReadLine()) !=null)
{
    lines.Add(new lh(line));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add your instances to a list:

```
List<lh> lhs = new List<lh>();
while ((line = ps.ReadLine()) != null)
    lhs.Add(new lh(line));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = new List<lh>();
while((line = ps.ReadLine()) !=null)
{
    list.Add(new lh(line));
}
```